# Loading data into Google Big Query without binary format

Tags: google-bigquery

Can you load csv file without opening in binary format

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google bigquery will not handle special characters when loading data from csv local storage that contains special characters